# responsive full screen background image that will show all it's content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mezaxzxd/2/show/
i am trying to make the image responsive in a way that if i re-size the screen all the image still show but in this demo the sword and the logo and even a part of the clock is being hidden , is there anyway to fix this ?

**HTML**

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <body></body>
```

**CSS**

```
  body{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rZBejVz.png ') no-repeat 50% 80% fixed; 
   background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
   }
```

Comment: Can't see anything in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noted that edges of your image have same color, thus you can use following trick!

```
body {background:#525256 url("http://i.imgur.com/rZBejVz.png ") no-repeat center bottom fixed; background-size: contain;}
```

Here a color is used as background & image is forced to fit in screen using `background-size: contain;`. Thus giving effect that image is covering entire page!

***P.S.:*** For this trick to work, re-confirm that edges of you image have same color!

See demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/mezaxzxd/4/

Comment: this is a good trick though i can't use it in my case because i want the logo and the sword to be in the left and the right corners of the screen

Comment: @Sora, but the are in left & right corners! Do you mean left & right bottom corners?

Comment: @Sora just change background-position to 'center bottom'

Comment: thank you for the answer , as much as i figure out it's difficult to get the perfect result ( the bird look to small when resizing the window ) , but i guess i can't get more than this trick . thank you for your help :D